# Angular work with observable after subscribe

Tags: angular, http, observable, ionic4

I am getting json data from API it contains detail of a device.

I display it at the beginning *ngOnInit()*. Then I have a button on the page

```
   <ion-button expand="block" *ngIf="device$ | async as device" (click)="makeAction(device)">{{decideActionText(device)}}</ion-button>
```

After I get the device, I want to change the state of the device with the button.

**The response should be added to the page**, instead, I am getting *undefined*

How can I work with same Observable in different places? 
How is this situation addressed properly?

**API**

https://device18.docs.apiary.io/#

**Component**

```
private device$: Observable<DeviceDetail>;

ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.device$ = this.deviceService.getDevice(id);
}

makeAction(device: DeviceDetail) {
    return this.deviceService.makeAction(device) 
    ... ?         
}
```

**Page**

```
<ion-content *ngIf="device$ | async as device">
<ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Status</ion-label>
            <ion-text>{{device.status}}</ion-text>
        </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<ion-row>
        <ion-col class="time" size="auto">
             <b>Time</b>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="time" size="auto" *ngFor="let time of device.values.timeStamp">
             {{time | date:'h:mm:ss'}}
        </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
 <ion-row>
        <ion-col class="value" size="auto">
            <b>Value</b>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="value" size="auto" *ngFor="let value of device.values.value">
            {{value}}
        </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

Thank you.

Comment: When is the method `getDevice `, emitted?

Comment: Right after going to the page. `ngOnInit() {
        this.getDevice();
    }`

Comment: `makeAction` will be fired OnInit as well?

Comment: No it's fired after clicking a button `<ion-button expand="block" (click)="makeAction(device)">{{decideActionText(device)}}</ion-button>`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the `*ngIf` structural directive to your `<ion-button>`, `<ion-list>`, and `<ion-row>` elements. This is because `device` is returned asynchronously, hence you would not want the DOM element to be rendered before the observable has been returned.

```
 <ion-button expand="block" (click)="makeAction(device)" *ngIf="device">{{decideActionText(device)}}</ion-button>
```

Comment: The same *undefined* result, the problem is that `makeAction(device)` is fired right after getting the device. It should be called after clicking a button.

Comment: @FrankMa Wait, why is it fired on that block? You didn't include the `makeAction` method OnInit or something, right?

Comment: Can you remove `return` on your `makeAction()`?

Comment: The way I was thinking is I am fetching the detail *onInit* and after user decide they want to command something, they push the button which sends a post request. The response from the server should be added back to the page.

Comment: Such that it is only `this.deviceService.makeAction(device)
            .subscribe((res)......`